# Prevent latex from putting big figure alone on the page

Tags: floats

I have a figure which occupies around 75% of the page and Latex keeps putting this figure alone on a page (in the middle of the page). What I want is to have some of the lines of the following paragraph right after the figure, even if there is space for only 4 or 5 lines. I tried with `\nopagebreak` and `minipage`, but nothing seems to work. Thanks!

EDIT: I fixed it by setting the [ht] parameters for the figure.

Comment: You can do `\begin{figure*}` which will put the figure where LaTeX see fits and text should follow above or below it as much as possible.

Comment: nope, not working

Comment: Can you post a picture of what it looks on the page?  My guess would be with the margins and the size there is no feasible room to have any text.  You could adjust the margins, check the bounding box of the figure, or scale down the figure.

Comment: @dustin that is _not_ what `figure*` does.

Comment: LaTeX does not allow floats on test pages to exceed a specified fraction of the page. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020 for the parameters you can set.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle doesn't it float where it is most appropriate and if possible text will go above or below it?

Comment: @dustin  in a single column document `figure*` is the same as `figure`